# how to filter only the apis which are anottated with my custom annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, filter

how to set Filter config that will filter only apis with this annotation  Loggable?

```
//custom annotation

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Loggable {
}

@Loggable
@Postmapping
public String  foo(){
return "";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research because I thought this as an interesting topic. It turns out what you are trying to do isn't possible with filters, but it is with AOP. This blog describes exactly what you need: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-annotation

The reason you can't do this with filters is because when the filter is invoked, it has not yet been determined what method will get called. This is determined in the DispatcherServlet, which is executed after the filters. For more information about this see these blogs:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/servlet-filters.html
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dispatcherservlet

I do think the AOP implementation outlined in the blog has a small problem. If an exception gets thrown by the annotaded method, I don't think the execution time gets logged. You can remedy this by simply wrapping joinPoint.proceed in a try/catch block (in step 7)

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for:

```
if (annotation.annotationType().equals(CustomAnnotationType.class)) {}
```

Comment: i tried to write that in filter, buy it says "cannot resolve symbol 'anottation' ".